# Maximality of normalizer of $p$-Sylow groups in the symmetric group $S_{p}$

Tags: gr.group-theory

Consider the symmetric group $S_{p}$ where $p$ is a prime, then its $p$-Sylow subgroups are isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_{p}$. And it is clear that the normalizer of this cyclic group in the symmetric group is $N_{S_{p}}(C_{p})\cong C_{p}\rtimes F_{p}^{\times}$.

> My question is about how to show that this normalizer is a maximal subgroup of this symmetric group. Is there a simple group theoretic argument?

Comment: On the contrary, I am pretty sure that the only known proof requires the classification of finite simple groups.

Comment: I misread the question. Sorry.

Comment: Restatement of the question: let $\mathrm{Aff}(F_p)$ be the group (of order $p(p-1)$ of affine automorphisms of the 1-dimensional line $F_p$, $p$ a given prime. How to show that $\mathrm{Aff}(F_p)$ is a maximal subgroup in the permutation group $\mathrm{Sym}(F_p)$?

Comment: One immediate remark: any intermediate subgroup $Aff(F_p)\le G\le Sym(F_p)$ has a simple normal subgroup, which is non-abelian as soon as $Aff(F_p)<G$ (so $Aff(F_p)$ is maximal solvable). Indeed, let $N$ be a minimal nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$. Since $N\neq 1$, by primitivity, $N$ has to be transitive, and in particular $p$ divides $|N|$. Also, as a minimal normal subgroup, $N\simeq S^k$ for some simple group $S$. Since $p^2$ does not divide $|S_p|$, we have $k=1$, so $N$ is simple. So either $N=F_p$ and hence $G$ is contained in its normaliser $Aff(F_p)$, or $N$ is non-abelian simple.

Comment: Peter Neumann proved and surveyed some results on groups of prime degree. For instance a group properly containing $\text{AGL}_1(\mathbb F_p)$ is $3$-transitive, and as of 1973 it was an open problem (raised by Wielandt) whether the group is $S_p$. It wasn't even known whether the group need to be $4$-transitive. See Neumann's survey `Transitive permutation groups of prime degree' in Proc. 2nd Internat. Conf. Theory of Groups, Canberra 1973, Lect. Notes Math. 372, 520-535 (1974).

Answer (score 9):

It was proved by Burnside that a permutation group of prime degree must either be solvable, in which case it has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup and is contained in the affine group, or it is $2$-transitive. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310200) for a recent straightforward proof of this.

The classification of the finite $2$-transitive groups was completed as an application of the classification of finite simple groups (see [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-transitive_group) or the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242221) for references) and they are listed for example in Section 7.7 of Dixon and Mortimer's book on permutation groups.

A look through the list shows that the only examples of prime degree are affine groups, $A_p$, $S_p$, groups $G$ with ${\rm PSL}(d,q) \le G \le {\rm P \Gamma L}(d,q)$ when $(q^d-1)/(q-1)$ is prime, and a few small examples (${\rm PSL}(2,7)$ and ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$ of degrees $7$ and $11$, $M_{11}$, and $M_{23}$).

When $(q^d-1)/(q-1)$ is prime $p$, an element of order $p$ in ${\rm PSL}(d,q)$ is a Singer cycle, and its normalizer in ${\rm P \Gamma L}(d,q)$ has order at most $pde$, where $q=r^e$ with $r$ prime, which is smaller than $p(p-1)$.
The small examples are all contained in the alternating groups.

So the affine group of order $p(p-1)$ is maximal in $S_p$ whenever $p>3$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson That's true, but I mentioned Burnside's result because it definitely does not use CFSG.

Answer (score 6):

I can't answer the question, but here is a remark to indicate that it can't be expected to be entirely straightforward (without the classification of finite simple groups). Note that ( for $p >2$) the Sylow $p$-normalizer in $S_{p}$ contains a $(p-1)$-cycle, hence an odd permutation. The even permutations in that normalizer form a subgroup $E_{p}$ of order $\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$ of the alternating group $A_{p}.$ However, $E_{p}$ is not necessarily a maximal subgroup of $A_{p}.$ For example, we have $E_{7} < {\rm PSL}(2,7) < A_{7}$ and, even worse, $E_{11} < {\rm PSL}(2,11) < M_{11} < A_{11}$ (all indicated inclusions are strict).