# Is there a 2 transitive finite group with transitive normal subgroup having a cyclic quotient other than $A_n$ and $S_n$?

Tags: finite-groups, permutation-groups

Let $G \leq S_n$ be $2$-transitive other than $A_n$ and $S_n$. Is it possible that there exists $N\lhd G$ with $N\neq G$, $N$ transitive and $G/N$ cyclic?

I am interested mostly in the answer when $n$ is large and also when the group $G$ is $3$-transitive.

Comment: $G = S_n$ and $N = A_n$?

Comment: Other than that, I forgot to mention it. I will fix the question

Comment: I suppose you want $G \neq N$ as well. For all $n \geq 2$ there is a classification of $n$-transitive groups, so I guess a starting point would be looking at these lists for examples.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that too. Sorry for being sloppy.

Comment: $PGL_n(F_q)$ and $PSL_n(F_q)$ should do the trick I think, the determinant on $PGL_n(F_q)$ is a well-defined element of the group $(F_q^*) / (F_q^*)^n$, which can be non-trivial (and always non-trivial for n=2, q odd).

For $n=2$ you will also get $3$-transitivity of $G$, not $N$ though.

Comment: Now that you've added $N\neq G$, you can remove $A_n$ as an exception..

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Good point, but I think you mean non-trivial *normal* subgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $G = \operatorname{Aut}(M_{22})$ and $N = M_{22}$, with the action of $M_{22}$ on $22$ points you have $N \triangleleft G < S_{22}$. Here both $N$ and $G$ are $3$-transitive, and $G/N \cong C_2$.

Answer (score 5):

The  most obvious family of examples is $AGL(1,q)$ for $q$ a prime power.

As spin said in the comments, finite $2$-transitive groups are classified. They are all almost simple or of affine type (like the example I gave). The almost simple ones are quite explicitly listed, so you would just have to go through the list. You should get plenty more examples. The classification of affine ones is a little less explicit (see [Have finite doubly transitive groups been classified?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242221/have-finite-doubly-transitive-groups-been-classified))