# Subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}(n,q)$ transitive on non-zero vectors

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Is there a classification of subgroups $G$ of $\operatorname{GL}(n,q)$ which act transitively on $\mathbb{F}_q^n \setminus \{0\}$, the set of non-zero vectors?

Any $G$ with $\operatorname{GL}(n/m,q^m) \leq G \leq \Gamma \operatorname{L}(n/m,q^m)$ for some $m \mid n$ is an example, since then $G$ contains a Singer cycle. Another example is $\operatorname{Sp}(2d,q)$ in $\operatorname{GL}(2d,q)$.

Comment: There is a list of transitive finite linear groups in Wikipedia.

Comment: These is essentially equivalent to the classification of finite double transitive groups of affine type. There is a long discussion of this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242221/). The consensus appears to be that they were classified by Hering, but there appears to be a dearth of precise references.

Comment: In Thm 15.1 (p. 197) of https://www.iazd.uni-hannover.de/fileadmin/iazd/sambale/pdfs/lnm.pdf there is a precise list of the exceptional groups including ids to libraries.

Comment: Martin Liebeck's paper "The affine permutation groups of rank three" contains an appendix where he states and proves Hering's theorem. This theorem gives an explicit list of the groups you are interested in. I have an e-copy of the paper and can email it to you if you want...